# Не могу получить данные из базы Postgres на Golang

Tags: postgresql, golang

выполняю следующий запрос в базе:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_name ~ '^\w+_(\d{9}|\d{12})_(\w+)$'
```

получаю данные:

```
im_948727345_2c773a6ebfa6e8fa
im_948727345_f43fc0987627a8d7
im_948727345_02
im_948727345_15620eb732f93f81
```

пытаюсь то же самое получить через Golang:

```
    var oooo = `select  table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name ~ '^\w+_(\d{9}|\d{12})_(\w+)$'`

    rows, _ := db.Query(oooo)
    cols, _ := rows.Columns()

    data := make(map[string]string)

    if err != nil {

        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Println("Error = ", err)
    }

    if rows.Next() {
        columns := make([]string, len(cols))
        fmt.Println("Из базы", len(cols))
        columnPointers := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
        for i, _ := range columns {
            columnPointers[i] = &columns[i]
            fmt.Println("Из базы5", i)

        }

        rows.Scan(columnPointers...)

        for i, colName := range cols {
            data[colName] = columns[i]
            fmt.Println("Из базы2", data[colName])
            fmt.Println("Из базы3", columns[0])
            fmt.Println("Из базы4", cols)

        }
    }
```

получаю:

```
Из базы 1
Из базы5 0
Из базы2 im_948727345_2c773a6ebfa6e8fa
Из базы3 im_948727345_2c773a6ebfa6e8fa
Из базы4 [table_name]
```

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема

Comment: Вы не получаете список колонок у таблиц потому что не делаете запрос для этого. Вам выдается список с таблицами в БД, НО вы затем не делаете запрос на получение колонок для каждой из таблиц вида ( SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'some_table')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

операция `if`  выполняется один раз. 
`rows.Next()` возвращает true если есть следующая строка и курсор перемещает на следующую строку. 
строчку `if rows.Next() {` можно прочитать как "если есть хоть одна строка данных"

для того чтобы прочитать все строки из базы, надо пройтись несколько раз до тех пор пока `rows.Next()` истина.

заменяем `if rows.Next()` на `for rows.Next()`